# staticfilecache don't load in TYPO3 8

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I try to use the [statcfilecache extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/staticfilecache) in a TYPO3 8.7 but it don't load the static files from file system.

I have added the sample htaccess snipped from [here](https://github.com/lochmueller/staticfilecache/blob/master/Documentation/Configuration/Htaccess.rst) in the standard TYPO3 htaccess file.

Static files are created, I can see it in the cache view of the backend modul and the files are placed in typo3temp but on page load by a not logged in frontend user the normal page is loaded and not the static file. Realurl is installed and working, btw.

I tried it on several TYPO3 instances: On TYPO3 9 it works as expected, in TYPO3 8 I don't get it working.

Are there any configurations in TYPO3 or in htaccess which prevent the loading of the static files ore any other hint for what went wrong here?

Comment: Which version of EXT:staticfilecache do you use?

Comment: The version is 9.0.0

Comment: Thanks Julian, your question took me on the right path. It was the wrong htaccess snipped. With the Version for 9.0.0 it works as expected.